# Spyder 5 keeps inserting parenthesis after variable even when disabled

Tags: python, autocomplete, spyder

I am using the latest Spyder 5.3.3 and notice that almost any time I enter a variable id adds () to the end.
It does not happen all the time, but most of the time.
I noticed if I just make a variable testVar = 1 and print it it works normally. But if I take almost any variable from my code such as COUNT it does COUNT(). The code fails from the () as there is no such

```
testVar = 1
print(testVar)
print(COUNT())
```

COUNT is a variable and should never have parenthesis anyway.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The key part is that I have disabled Automatic insertion of pan theses.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

My guess is that this is a bug in Spyder, if so can someone please help me report it?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyQnN.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/isSjz.png

I found how to submit in Spyder with Help->Report issue which requires a github token.